# NET 6: Controller method is not reachable

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a simple NET 6 application. added a controller and trying to test.

Run it, I see method on Swagger page, execute the method in Swagger, it returns 200,  but it does not return "Hello World". Then I have added logger output to the controller constructor and to the method - no outputs.  What can be the reason of the problem? My Program file

```
using MTApp.Infra;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
//builder.Services.AddSession();// !
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSession(); //<--- add this line
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MTApp API V1");
    });
}
app.UseTenant();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

The extension:

```
public static class TenantSecurityMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseTenant(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<TenantSecurityMiddleware>();
        return app;
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace MTApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DobedoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DobedoController> _logger;
        public DobedoController(ILogger<DobedoController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("DobedoController");
        }
        [HttpGet("GetHW2")]
        public string GetHW2()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("DobedoController:HW2");
            return "Hello World2";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `app.UseTenant();` supposed to do?

Becase it works for me after:

- Creating a new .NET 7 web api using `dotnet new webapi`.
- Replacing the template controller with yours (missing `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` line at the top, but you probably have that in the global usings).
- Replacing the template `Program.cs` with yours.
- Commenting the line with `app.UseTenant()` (since it comes from `MTApp.Infra`).

Comment: I am trying to create multitenant app and Use.Tenant() it is extension just in Program.cs  (see in the start post, I have added it), But interesting why the error was

Comment: I have found the reason. Need to find another way to implement multitenancy. Thanx